# Displaying statistics with SceneKit (SCNView) (Swift 4 / iOS 11 beta)

Tags: swift, scenekit, swift4

I've been trying to get SCNView to display statistics on the Scene View, but showsStatstics doesn't seem to do anything.

Here's my code where I set SCNView.showsStatistics

```
  scnScene = SCNScene()
  scnView.scene = scnScene
```

However, this is a screenshot from the simulator running the app

[image]

As you can see, no statistics panel. What could be going on?

Comment: Almost anything. Please add your code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you cannot run AR apps from your simulator since there is no camera. Try using an actual device and see if the problem persists.